# How to destroy all 2D objects that collide with a specific 2D one in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I am trying to use a moving 2D collider as a "remover of objects" by destroying all the objects it collides with but having issues doing this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be sure to include any code you've attempted so far, so we get a better idea of your approach and can more easily write an answer that will meet your needs.

Comment: Generally on SO, people provide answers for specific questions -- no one likes to be a code-monkey for some guy online. However, I **can** give you a few hints to get you started. For starters, I see your task as requiring 2 phases: the collision detection phase and the object removal phase. You will definitely need to create a script to destroy the objects, so do you want the remover to destroy the other objects or do you want the other objects to detect a collision with the remover and then destroy themselves? Hope that helps you get started.

Answer (score 2):

`OnTriggerEnter`'s example [in the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) does exactly what you are asking for:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to check the collider to be a trigger. That script should be attached to the game object that is going to destroy stuff that touches it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I am making a 2D game, so you might need to adapt my code. You should set 'Is Trigger' on the collider to false (unchecked) and attach a javascript script to your 'remover of objects' and use the code below.

For 2D:

```
function OnCollisionEnter2D(coll: Collision2D) {
        Destroy(coll.gameObject);
}
```

For 3D:

```
function OnCollisionEnter(coll: Collision) {
        Destroy(coll.gameObject);
}
```

I'm not 100% sure if the 3D code will work.

Hope this helped! :)

Full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34862535/5792157

Comment: @Burga Alex if this helped, let me know! Oddly enough, OnTriggerEnter didn't work for me.